# How is a jazz bass different from a normal bass guitar?

Tags: bass-guitar, electric-bass-guitar

I'm trying to get a jazz bass guitar (active) and I've been looking at the Ibanez range. The only problem is that it doesn't quite say whether it is jazz bass or not for most of them. For example, how do I know this [Ibanez bass guitar](http://www.gear4music.com/Guitar-and-Bass/Ibanez-SR755-NTF-5-String-Bass-Guitar-Natural-Flat/162F) is a *jazz* bass?

The question is what makes a jazz bass guitar a jazz bass?

Comment: This question will probably be disallowed. Have a look at SGC Nanyo Bass collection, I use several, and have never heard a bad word about them. From late '80s/ 90s. If you pay £300 it'll be a little more than average for a much greater than average bass.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, the Jazz Bass refers to the [Fender Jazz Bass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fender_Jazz_Bass).

Per the above link, it was named 'Jazz Bass' because the creator, Leo Fender, thought that jazz bassists would feel more comfortable playing this kind of bass. This is a characteristic jazz bass:

[image]

Notice the pickups. Two singlecoil ones. There are similar basses from other companies, but they aren't names as such. If you see a bass like this, you might be able to refer to as jazz bass, but unless it's a fender bass, it would be technically wrong.

Comment: in addition he intended it to be played when sitting down.